# Could a method of preventing flag spam/abuse on chat be implemented?

Tags: feature-request, chat

I was wondering if there could be an addition of some kind of system on chat that would prevent a user from flagging for `X` amount of time in the instance that their last `Y` flags in `Z` time had been invalidated by the community.

At times it seems that some users do not understand the meaning of "offensive" or "spam" when flagging posts made by their fellow users and it can result in a lot of flags that just end up getting invalidated.

I'm not saying that this is consistently the case, sometimes I can go days without seeing a single flag pop up but then at times, there will be a sudden stream of flags for silly things that shouldn't be flagged all come through at once - I would speculate that it could be the same user taking offence to something when perhaps they should step back and take a deep breath... but I digress.

I'm not sure what the `X`, `Y` and `Z` would be in this instance, although my thought on it was 3 invalidated flags would result in a day without being able to flag, or something along those lines - something that would prevent the occasional invalid flag from locking you out from being able to raise more.

Think of it as a question ban but for flagging on chat I guess...

Comment: Mods also need to be able to trace spam/offensive flags. Had bit of a problem with those in the Math room recently.

Comment: A flagging timeout (==24 hours?) after an invalid flag should be simple?

Comment: After a single flag would probably be too harsh, after multiple flags would be the best way to do it IMO

Comment: I remember that flags on sites (aka no chat flags) if they result in too many flags declined the user can't flag anymore for... a fixed amount of time. I don't seems to find the same has been implemented in chat flags, tho.