# Let mods see the names of the flaggers for chat offensive flags

Tags: feature-request, flags, chat, moderator-tools

There have been [quite](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=9541781#9541781) [a](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12136967#12136967) [few](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11756530#11756530) (not to pick on the Bridge, just that these are the ones I found) occurrences where users abuse chat flags to cause drama. Random stuff gets flagged, and users from other rooms are needlessly summoned into the room.

The issue is, while mods can tell the room to stop flagging random things, there's no way to enforce this. Spam/offensive flags in chat are anonymous, and can be abused with impunity without the mods finding out. I don't think there's anything stopping a user from letting out an endless stream of flags, annoying everyone.

Can mods have the ability to see who flagged a message in chat?

Comment: related: [Could a method of preventing flag spam/abuse on chat be implemented?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178645/229699)

Comment: Apparently the data is actually exposed to mods, just without a UI. See http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12672900#12672900

Comment: @Mr.PeanutMonopolyMcManish That transcript link is 404ing on me.

Comment: It seems like the names of those who _validated_ the flags are shown in the flag dialog to diamonds now.

Comment: I would be surprised if it wouldn't be implemented until now. Maybe a "status-implemented" tag and an answer could be useful in this case.