# Make "who flagged this" data available to moderators for chat offensive flags

Tags: feature-request, flags, chat, moderator-tools

This has been [done before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211819/let-mods-see-the-names-of-the-flaggers-for-chat-offensive-flags), but never got a response. I'm bringing it up again (rather than simply reusing the last post which is effectively dead now) for a number of reasons, including that lack of response and the fact that there have been a few recent occasions where seeing this data would have made a significant difference in effective chat moderation.

Currently, there are two types of chat flag: offensive flags, and mod flags. On mod flags, moderators can see all the data about them: what message they were cast against, what the flag says, and who cast the flag. On offensive flags, we see only what 10k users see - which is only which message the flag was cast against.

It's a pretty well accepted fact that chat moderation is... not all it could be, shall we say. Well, this would make an improvement: there have been a number of cases that I've seen in my tenure of spam-spam-flagging (i.e. spamming spam/offensive flags). These events disrupt rooms by bringing in a Mjolnir of mods, and a plethora of 10k chat users from all over the network, all trying to get at the flags and (sometimes) have a dig at the room where they're cast.

Allowing mods to see who cast the flag would enable us to stop these cases in their tracks - we've got the tools to do it, but we don't know who to use them on.

Comment: Worth noting that this exists already, but mods can only see who spam/offensive flagged something if they moderate the parent site of the chatroom in question.

Comment: Oh, by the way, this would be nice for stars as well. Star abuse, while not the most severe of offenses, is still extremely annoying to deal with when it happens over and over and over again.

Comment: Why knowingly make a duplicate? Just add a bounty to the other question, and an answer if you have ideas and info etc to put forward. Having the same request in two places does not help the cause you are fighting for. Had you put a bounty on the other question instead of making this dupe, it would have had your 18 upvotes, and thereby **one** request with 35 upvotes, instead of two sharing those 35 upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to have been implemented now:

[image: chat flag dialog with circled text "(♦ only) flagged by:" and the names of the flaggers]
<sub>(names have been changed to protect the innocent)</sub>

The chatroom, The Awkward Silence, belongs to [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) and I'm not a moderator there.

Comment: Only works for pending flags; the flag history is not accessible.